# Python match lists unequal in length to columns

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can you take a list of lists of unequal length and write it to a series of columns while matching the order of another list?

```
order = ['bx', 'cs', 'lb', 'pc']

totals = [
    [{'unit': 'pc', 'sum': Decimal('3.00')}],
    [{'unit': 'bx', 'sum': Decimal('3.00')}, {'unit': 'pc', 'sum': Decimal('16.00')}],
    [{'unit': 'bx', 'sum': Decimal('6.00')}, {'unit': 'lb', 'sum': Decimal('24.00')}, {'unit': 'pc', 'sum': Decimal('63.00')}],
    [{'unit': 'pc', 'sum': Decimal('36.00')}],
    [{'unit': 'bx', 'sum': Decimal('31.00')}]
]

desired_format = [
    ['', '', '', '3.00 pc'],
    ['3.00 bx', '', '', '16.00 pc'],
    ['6.00 bx', '', '24.00 lb', '63:00 pc'],
    ['', '', '', '36:00 pc'],
    ['31.00 bx', '', '', ''],
]
```

I've tried below but it doesn't work as desired if all 4 units in order aren't present.

```
desired_format = [[]]
for total in totals:
    data = []
    for idx, um in enumerate(total):
        if um['unit'] == order[idx]:
            data.append(str(um['sum'] + ' ' + str(um['unit'])))
        else:
            data.append('')
    desired_format.append(data)
```

I've also tried this which ends up with too many empty columns and uneven/unordered columns

```
desired_format = [[]]
for total in totals:
    data = []
    for um in total:
        for unit in order:
            if um['unit'] == unit:
                data.append(str(um['sum'] + ' ' + str(um['unit'])))
            else:
                data.append('')
    desired_format.append(data)
```

Comment: In the first of you outputs, are you after
`['3.00 bx', '', '', '']` as you've stated or `['', '', '', '3.00 pc']`?

Comment: @Jon thanks, I've corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you the following code, based on your original post:

```
desired_format = []
for total in totals:
    data = []
    for orderValue in order:
        found = False
        for um in total:
            if um['unit'] == orderValue:
                found = True
                break
        if found:
            data.append(str(um['sum'] + ' ' + str(um['unit'])))
        else:
            data.append('')
    desired_format.append(data)

print(desired_format)
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't be the most efficient method

```
converters = [{dict['unit']: dict['sum'] for dict in total} for total in totals]
desired_format = [[str(converter[item])+' '+item if item in converter else '' for item in order] for converter in converters]
```

The idea is that your totals is a list of list of dictionaries. Converters turns it into a list of dictionaries using list comprehension

you can then do list comprehension on one of those dictionaries to iterate order through it: if the item in order is present, give the desired output, else give ''

There is probably a way to do this without generating converters first, which might make the code faster.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempts were pretty close, but contained a few issues (ignorming the lack of closing some brackets).

Firstly your initialising you list as `desiredFormat = [[]]`, which is creating a list and then making the first element an empty list. Instead you just need to create the empty list with `[]`, and then push your subsequent lists to it.

In addition, when looping the lists your creating new list elements for each section rather than over writing if a second object exists.

Try this:

```
desired_format = []
for total in totals:
    data = [''] * len(order)
    for um in total:
        for i, unit in enumerate(order):
            if um['unit'] == unit:
                data[i] = str(um['sum']) + ' ' + str(um['unit'])
    desired_format.append(data)
```

It's creating the empty list first, and then updating it with extra info as the lists get looped.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution via `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for idx, i in enumerate(totals):
    for j in order:
        d_item = next((str(k['sum']) + ' ' + j for k in i if k['unit'] == j), '')
        d[idx].append(d_item)

res = [d[i] for i in range(len(totals))]

# [['', '', '', '3.00 pc'],
#  ['3.00 bx', '', '', '16.00 pc'],
#  ['6.00 bx', '', '24.00 lb', '63.00 pc'],
#  ['', '', '', '36.00 pc'],
#  ['31.00 bx', '', '', '']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution relies on creating a table of dimension `len(order)` x `len(totals)` initially filled with the default value `''`. We then fill the table based on the known values in `totals`, leaving the rest as `''`.

```
# Have your order as dict for quick lookup
order_keys = dict(map(reversed, enumerate(order)))
# This output the indexing: {'bx': 0, 'cs': 1, 'lb': 2, 'pc': 3}

# Create the empty table for the desired output, default value will be ''
output = [[''] * len(order_keys) for _ in range(len(totals))]
# output:
# [['', '', '', ''],
#  ['', '', '', ''],
#  ['', '', '', ''],
#  ['', '', '', ''],
#  ['', '', '', '']]

for index, row in enumerate(totals):
    for col in row:
        unit = col['unit']
        output[index][order_keys[unit]] = '{} {}'.format(col['sum'], col['unit'])

# output:
# [['', '', '', '3.00 pc'],
#  ['3.00 bx', '', '', '16.00 pc'],
#  ['6.00 bx', '', '24.00 lb', '63.00 pc'],
#  ['', '', '', '36.00 pc'],
#  ['31.00 bx', '', '', '']]
```